# Closing Gaps Between Strips in Video Editing

Tags: video-sequence-editor

After cutting out a ton of footage in a video, I'm left with a LOT of gaps. Yes, I did find the [Remove Gaps] option, yes I also tried pressing [Backspace], but- they only worked once, on about half of my project but not the first half that was within the render time region I set at first, even though I only had one strip selected. I've tried doing what I did at first, I've moved the Sequencer head, I've lowered the render time frame and I'm simply at a loss because Stitching the gaps together manually would be painful when there's already a command that's supposed to do it instantly. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? I even updated to the latest version of Blender. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Remove Gaps operator only works if there is a gap at the playhead position in all channels. So if you're editing ex. a music video move the audio strip out of the way, remove all the gaps one by one, by placing the playhead in a gap and hit backspace.
[image]

I once did a patch to do proper ripple deleting in Blender, but it was never accepted: https://developer.blender.org/D7767

Neither was a similar function done by a BF dev: https://developer.blender.org/D9979

I have no idea why this isn't a priority to add in Blender.

Comment: Thank you! I've only now seen this because I took a break from editing my project, but moving the audio out of the way like you suggested was exactly what I needed to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you move time cursor to the start of the video you can remove all the gaps using the remove gaps operator (backspace by default).[image]